# Static DNS resolver in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to build a fast DNS resolver in c++ with static libraries (work everywhere). So far so good  my version uses `gethostbyname` and **on some servers it doesn't work** i get `A non-recoverable name server error occurred (NO_RECOVERY)`. Also when compiling we are getting this warning :

`Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

// for dom
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* host = "google.com";
    int debugLevel = 5;
    char* ip_of_domain;
    struct hostent *he;

    he = gethostbyname(host);

    if (he == NULL)
    {
        switch(h_errno)
        {
            case HOST_NOT_FOUND:
                if(debugLevel >= 3) puts("The host was not found.");
                break;
            case NO_ADDRESS:
                if(debugLevel >= 3) puts("The name is valid but it has no address.");
                break;
            case NO_RECOVERY:
                if(debugLevel >= 3) puts("A non-recoverable name server error occurred.");
                break;
            case TRY_AGAIN:
                if(debugLevel >= 3) puts("The name server is temporarily unavailable.");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ip_of_domain = strdup(inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *) he->h_addr_list[0])));
    }
    if(debugLevel >= 4) printf("IP=%s\n",ip_of_domain);
}
```

The program has to be compatible every where, 32 and 64 bits.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a DNS resolver. It is a tiny utility application that uses the OS's DNS resolver. Have your users use the OS's built-in tools instead of attempting to wrap them with a generic, catch-all program. The warning seems pretty explanatory. What do you mean by "on some servers"?

Comment: "static libraries" and "run everywhere" are pretty much mutually exclusive as they bind you to a specific system call interface, and system call interfaces are not standardized at all.  At least a dynamic library-call level interface is standard, even if somewhat variable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit on this server `2.6.18-371.8.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Apr 24 18:23:07 EDT 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
` works, it is resolving, on this `Linux docker-test 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` it dosen't ... and this part that you say `uses the OS's DNS resolver` clearly say that i have to use another library/functions beside `gethostbyname`, that is certain it seems ...

Comment: There are existing standalone, real, DNS resolvers that can be used as static libraries, not merely thin wrappers for gethostbyname (including one that I wrote). But, a question on that is clearly off-topic here...

Comment: Well if you want to implement a DNS resolver then go ahead, but making a system call asking the OS to resolve DNS for you is not implementing a DNS resolver.

Comment: @DancoD *and this part that you say uses the OS's DNS resolver clearly say that i have to use another library/functions beside gethostbyname, that is certain it seems ...* That error message is telling you that you **can not** statically link `gethostbyname()` because of the way it's implemented in glibc - you need the glibc shared libraries to make that work. It is not telling you the DNS resolver didn't work - it's telling you you built an incomplete program that needs specific shared libraries. As I commented earlier, "static linking" and "run everywhere" are pretty much mutually exclusive.

Comment: so the only way is to get a third party library, do you know any good dns libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Use c-ares library, here: https://c-ares.haxx.se/. This is a true OS-independent resolver.

Comment: thank you for the answer. how do i install this? `./configure make make install` style? sorry if the question is a little bit off topic, i used only `curl` as an external library before ...

Comment: Exactly. The project also has a nice overview of competing libs, see https://c-ares.haxx.se/otherlibs.html.